# Show that in every (not necessarily connected) graph there is a path from every vertex u of odd degree to some other vertex v...

Tags: graph-theory

Show that in every (not necessarily connected) graph there is a path from every vertex $u$ of odd degree to some other vertex $v$ ($u \neq v$), also of odd degree.

Answer (score 6):

If there isn't then $u$ is in a connected component consisting of itself and vertices of even degree. But then the sum of degrees in that connected component is odd, which it can't be, since it counts every edge twice.

Comment: More elegant than mine.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Let $u$ be vertex of odd degree. Start at $u$ and walk from vertex to vertex, never repeating an edge, until you can’t proceed any further.

Comment: More animated than mine.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion holds in finite graphs, but no finiteness assumption was stated. For an infinite counterexample consider the natural numbers with edges connecting each number and its successor.  Only one vertex has odd degree.

Comment: More complete than mine.